# How to update View when model is loaded

Tags: ember.js

Emberjs is able to uptade automagically the view when the model is loaded. For example, with the following template

```
{{#each controller}}
    {{name}}   
{{each}}
```

the view is updated each time a model in the controller is loaded.

But, what if we need to implement a custom view that does not support such feature. Precisely, I need a view that render a graphic chart. I use some third party library for that. The data that I have in my controller represent some points that my view should render as a chart. Usually with these third party library we need to set the data and then call the `draw` function.

The problem is that when I just bind my `controller.model` to my `chart` data, the chart have no idea if these data are really loaded and the `draw` function crashes. So I think, I need some observers somewhere but I can't figure out where to put it. My attempt is to observer `controller.model.isLoaded` and call `draw` when it changes. But it just works once, and when I go back and forth on my route, the `draw` is no more called because the model are all loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a conditional around the insertion of your view.

```
{{#if controller.model.isLoaded}}
Put your chart view in here
{{/if}}
```

The view will only be rendered once the model has loaded

Answer (score 0):

You can switch from the `model` property that you are binding against to a wrapper `chartData` property. The `chartData` property can then be made dependent on both `model` and `lastUpdate`. Finally add an `update()` method that refreshes the `lastUpdate` property. Calling update would then automatically trigger a refresh of the chartData binding and hence the chart.

```
lastUpdate: new Date(),

chartData: function() {
  return this.get('model');
}.property('model', 'lastUpdate'),

update: function() {
  this.set('lastUpdate', new Date());
}
```